# How to get new files from a different branch [git]?

Tags: git

Hi I'm pretty new with git so please bear with me.
Say, I'm currently on a branch:

```
remotes/origin/dev-1.1
```

And my colleague created some new files and updated some old ones on a different branch:

```
remotes/origin/dev-1.2
```

I want to update my local files so that I can work with the new files and updated ones. Should I be using `git checkout remotes/origin/dev-1.2` to update my local directory? Or are there additional steps I have to take to download the new and updated files?

Answer (score 1):

> Say I'm currently on ... `remotes/origin/dev-1.1`

You aren't.  This part of Git is pretty confusing, but it's also important.

> ... And my colleague created some new files and updated some old ones on ... `remotes/origin/dev-1.2`

Technically, your colleague simply created some new *commits*, which you're finding through the *name* `remotes/origin/dev-1.2`.

The tricky part here is that it's wrong to say that some particular files are "on" any particular *branch*.  Where files are, in Git, is *inside commits*.  The commits themselves are on branches, but—this is why this is confusing—*each commit can be on any number of branches*, anywhere from zero branches, to every branch.  Moreover, the very word *branch* is ambiguous.  (See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

To help make this more concrete, say we have some commit whose ID is `a123456`.<sup>1</sup>  Commit `a123456` holds some set of files.  The particular *versions* of those files are frozen into `a123456` for all time.  As long as you have that commit in your repository,<sup>2</sup> you can have Git reach into it and pull out either the entire set of those files, or any one file from that commit, as it's stored in that commit.

But: commit `a123456` might be on `feature` right now, and then later, it might be on both `feature` *and* `dev`, and in the future, it might be on both `dev` *and* `master` / `main`.  At this point you might have deleted the *name* `feature`, now that the feature is merged.  Commit `a123456` is *still there* but with the name `feature` gone, it's not *on* `feature`, which doesn't even exist.  It's now only on `dev` and `main`, or whatever.  Create a new branch and now it's probably on *all three* branches.

If you rename a branch, that branch still contains all the commits it contained before, but it has a different name now.  Instead of `feature`, maybe it's now `feat-123` so that you can work on `feat-124` too.  The key to all of this is to think of the branch names as *ways to find commits*.  It's the commit hash IDs—the `a123456` style random-looking numbers—that are the "true names" of each commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actual Git commit hash IDs are much longer and are random-looking.  They're not at all random, really, but they *look* random.  Each commit has a unique number—expressed in hexadecimal like this—that we can shorten by referring to it by some unique prefix of its full ID.  As a repository fills up with more and more stuff in the database, the length of the prefix needed to get something unique gets longer, to the point where clones of the Linux kernel need 10 to 12 characters from the front of some hash ID, sometimes.

<sup>2</sup>Git is also built to only ever *add* commits to the repository.  There are some ways to get rid of bad commits, should that be necessary, but they're tricky.  Commits are almost viral in the way they spread from Git repository to Git repository, and if you've let your Git have Git-sex with another Git repository and given it commits, those commits may come back to you later, "re-infecting" your repository, even if you've gotten rid of them on purpose.  You don't normally need to worry about this: if you have a hash ID, you probably got it *from* your Git, and it's the hash ID of something *in* your Git, and you probably want to keep it.

---

#### Branch names vs remote-tracking names

In Git, a *branch* name is a way to find commits.  But *branch* names are not the *only* way.  You can of course use the raw hash ID.  To do that, most people will use cut-and-paste with their mouse or whatever: they're too hard to type in correctly.  But that, too, is not the only way.  Git has lots of different *kinds* of names.  Each kind of name has a different purpose.  Your branch names are for *you* to use, to find commits that you, for whatever reason, think are significant.

The name `remotes/origin/dev-1.1` is what I call a *remote-tracking name*.<sup>3</sup>  A remote-tracking name is a name in your own Git repository that corresponds to some *branch* name in some *other* Git repository.  If branch names find commits—and they do, in a way we'll see below—then, when you get *new* commits from some *other* Git repository, your own Git repository is going to need a way to find these new commits.  Your Git *could* write these names into your branch names, but this would create a problem:

- Suppose you made a new commit that Bob (or whoever) doesn't have.  You find this commit with your branch name `feature`.
- Suppose Bob made a new commit that you don't have.  Bob finds this commit with *his* branch name `feature`.
- You connect your Git to Bob's Git, and get his commit.  If your Git sticks his commit number into your name `feature`, your Git *loses your new commit*.  (It's still *in* there—at least for a while—but it's become hard to *find*.)

So your Git doesn't do that.  Instead, you tell your Git about Bob's Git repository: you say to your Git *to get commits from Bob's Git, reach out to URL _____* (fill in the blank here with the right URL).  When your Git does this and gets his new commit from *his* branch `feature`, your Git creates or updates your *remote-tracking name* `bob/feature`.

This means that your remote-tracking names are *not* **branch** names.  They're just as good as branch names for *some* purposes, and Git documentation uses the phrase *remote-tracking branch name*, and many humans refer to these as *branches*.  But they're not *branch names*.  We'll see in a moment why this distinction really matters.

---

<sup>3</sup>Git calls this a *remote-tracking branch name*.  The word *branch* here, in this four-word phrase, serves mainly to clutter up the phrase and mislead people into shortening the phrase to *remote branch*, which is way too easy to mix up with the notion of a *branch* name on some remote repository.  So I've taken to calling it a *remote-tracking name*, which isn't great, but at least doesn't add yet another form of "branch".

---

#### Commits form chains

What's missing from the above picture, and is absolutely key to making sense of Git, is the notion of *chaining commits together*.  Git strings commits together, one after another—or more precisely, one *before* another.  But it doesn't do this by names: it does this using the commits themselves.

Each commit holds a snapshot of every file—that's its main data, more or less—but each commit also holds information *about* the commit itself: who made it, when, and why, for instance, with the *why* part being the log message.<sup>4</sup>  In this same metadata, Git stores something just for Git's use: each commit stores the raw hash ID of some earlier commit, or commits.  This makes commits link, in a backwards-looking fashion, to what Git calls their *parents*.

When we have a simple series of commits all in a row, we can draw this.  Let's let a single uppercase letter stand in for each real hash ID, and make a small picture like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *last* commit in this series.  It contains a snapshot of files, but it also has metadata: who made commit `H`, when, and so on.  In that metadata, commit `H` holds the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

Commit `G`, of course, has a snapshot and metadata.  The metadata for commit `G` holds the hash ID of earlier commit `F`.

Git can take any two snapshots, such as `G` and `H`, and compare them.  When files are identical in both commits, Git will say nothing about those files.  When two files are *different* in the two commits, Git can produce a recipe by which the earlier commit's copy of that file can be changed to match the later commit's copy.  This is how Git can show us commits—which are snapshots—*as* changes, even though commits don't *hold* changes.  We just take a pair of adjacent commits and ask Git to compare (`diff`) them.

---

<sup>4</sup>This is why it's a good idea to write a good log message: anyone can come along later and see *what* you did, but they won't necessarily know *why* you did it.  Describing a bug, including how to reproduce the bug, is quite valuable when examining code that's supposed to fix that bug.  Describing a new feature is valuable when examining code that's supposed to add that feature.  The code expresses *how* but not necessarily *why*.

---

#### Names find the last commit in a chain

Now we can see how branch and other names work.  To work backwards through the chain of commits that ends at commit `H`, Git will need the actual hash ID of commit `H`.  But hash IDs are big and ugly and not good for humans.  We like *names*, that mean something to us, like `main` and `dev` and `feature`.  We could create a file (outside the repository perhaps) and put our hash IDs in there, but it makes more sense to have Git do it for us:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

That's a branch name.  Once we create a *second* branch name, also pointing to commit `H`, we'll need a way to remember which *name* we're using:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, main (HEAD)
```

If we run `git checkout dev` or `git switch dev`, we're telling Git that we want the files from commit `H` out—they're already out, because they were out for `main`—but we want to be "on" branch `dev`, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), main
```

**Here's why this matters:**  When we make a *new* commit, Git will:

- gather up source files for a snapshot;
- gather up metadata (name, email, date-and-time, etc);
- add the *current* commit's hash ID as the parent of the new commit;
- write all this out to *make* the new commit, getting a new unique hash ID that we'll call `I` here; and
- last and perhaps sneakiest, **write the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name*.

The effect of that is that we now have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

That is, the *name* `dev` now selects commit `I`, not commit `H`.  Commit `H` is the *parent* of commit `I`, so that `I` *points back to* `H`.  Commits up through `H` are still on both branches, but now commit `I` is only on branch `dev`.

(Later, we can have Git move the name `main` in such a way as to have commit `I` be on `main`, *if* it turns out that this is a good idea.  If not, we can completely drop the name `dev` and with it, the way to find commit `I`.  If we haven't sent commit `I` anywhere else, no other Git has commit `I` and it won't come back.  So this is how and why commits aren't necessarily permanent.  But as long as commit `I` *exists*, it *will* still have those files in it, along with that metadata, because no part of any commit can ever be changed—not even by Git itself.)

#### The special feature of `HEAD` only works with *branch* names

We finally get to the reason for all of the words above.  When you run:

```
git checkout dev
```

or:

```
git switch dev
```

Git will *find or create a branch name* (or else fail; the method by which it creates new branch names is somewhat fancy and we haven't described this yet).  When you use `git branch` or `git checkout -b` or `git switch -c` to create a new branch name, you must pick some existing commit, and Git will create the new branch name pointing to that commit.  In all of these cases, what you get really **is** a **branch** name, and `git checkout` and `git switch` can attach the special name `HEAD` *to* that branch name, as shown above.

With other forms of name, though, including *remote-tracking names* like `origin/dev-1.1`, Git will *refuse to attach the special name `HEAD` to that other name*.  What this means is that you won't be "on" **any** branch at all.  The `git checkout` command will put you into *detached HEAD* mode.  It will do this without asking whether you understand all the consequences of this mode.  The new (since Git 2.23) `git switch` command is better about this: it requires that you use the `--detach` flag to indicate that you understand that you're going into detached HEAD mode.

In detached HEAD mode, you still have a commit checked out.  It's just that you're not *on* any branch.  That's all there is to it, really, but that has a big consequence.  Let's take our example above:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

and now go into detached HEAD mode by using:

```
git checkout --detach dev
```

(which is an explicit way to say to `git checkout` that you want the same commit, but want to enter detached HEAD mode).  The result looks like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- HEAD, dev
```

That is, the name `HEAD` finds commit `I` directly, without going through the name `dev`.  If we now make a new commit `J`, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- dev
           \
            J   <-- HEAD
```

The new commit is made, but `HEAD` is the only way to *find* it.

Git *really needs* the hash ID.  Whenever you use a name like `dev` or `HEAD`, Git has to translate that name *to* a hash ID.  Use `git rev-parse` to see how this works, e.g., run:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

for instance.

Well, now suppose we've made commit `J`, then we decide we want to go look at `main` for a moment.  We run `git checkout main` to do that, and get this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          I   <-- dev
           \
            J   ???
```

The `git checkout` command has gone and *re-attached* our `HEAD`, to the name `main` this time, to get Git to extract commit `H` for us to look at and maybe work on.  Now we can create and switch to a new branch name `feature`:

```
git checkout -b feature
```

and make another new commit `K`:

```
          K   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- dev
           \
            J   ???
```

That's great, but now we want to go get something from commit `J`.  But ... how are we going to *find* it?  If we wrote down the hash ID, or it's still in scrollback on the screen, that could rescue us.  But mostly, this is just a bad idea.  The only time to work in a detached `HEAD` like this is:

- when you're looking at a historical commit, for whatever reason (including `git checkout` of a tag, which does that); or
- when you're in the middle of a `git rebase`, because rebase uses detached HEAD mode internally.  Once you finish up the rebase, Git will re-attach `HEAD`—or if you decide the rebase is a bad idea, you can use `git rebase --abort` and Git will put everything back and re-attach `HEAD`, but either way, you're back into "attached HEAD" mode (Git doesn't call it that: it just says "on a branch", but that's the obvious opposite of detached HEAD mode).

#### Remote-tracking names and creating your own branches

It's time now to note how the remote-tracking names work.  Suppose you've *cloned* some repository, using `git clone`.  That other repository has a *short name* in your own Git repository.  The standard short name for this is `origin` (though you can pick some other one if you like).

That other repository has branches.  It may have only a `main` or `master`, but chances are it has more branches than that.  Your Git has copied their Git repository's commits.  These commits are literally exactly the same in both repositories: they have the same "real name" hash ID, and each one points backwards to the same previous hash ID and hence forms the same chains.  But *their* Git's *branch* names have become *your* Git's *remote-tracking names*.  So instead of:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- main
         \
          J--K   <-- dev
```

what you have, initially, in your own repository is:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- origin/main
         \
          J--K   <-- origin/dev
```

(Aside: the *full* name of a branch name like `main` is `refs/heads/main`.  The full name of `origin/main` is `refs/remotes/origin/main`.  Git lets you take `refs/` off, or even `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/`.  So that's why we get by with simple branch names and simple `origin/*` remote-tracking names.  If you run `git branch -r`, Git will list your remote-tracking names as `origin/whatever`, but if you use `git branch -a`, it lists them as `remotes/origin/whatever`.  It's not consistent, but both work, so it's not that big a deal.)

As soon as `git clone` has finished cloning their Git repository, however, your own Git goes and *creates* some branch name.<sup>5</sup>  The name your `git clone` creates is the one you tell it to, with your `-b` option.  If you don't give your `git clone` a `-b` option, your Git asks their Git what name *they* recommend, and creates that one.  So one way or another, you get an initial branch name.  Your Git then checks out this branch name:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          J--K   <-- origin/dev
```

(assuming you used `-b main`, or they recommended `main`).  You now have commit `I` out and are on your own branch named `main`.

If you now run `git checkout dev` or `git switch dev`, your Git looks at *your* branch names for one spelled `dev` (more precisely, for `refs/heads/dev`).  This **does not exist** so the obvious thing to do would be to produce an error message and quit.  But instead, your Git will now root through your *remote-tracking names*.  If one of them is close enough to `dev`—if it came from someone else's `dev`, in other words—your Git will *create* your `dev`, using that remote-tracking name to pick the commit:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          J--K   <-- dev, origin/dev
```

Having *created* the branch name, your Git can now *switch to* that commit—in this case, commit `K`—and attach your `HEAD`:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          J--K   <-- dev (HEAD), origin/dev
```

This is *very similar* to `git checkout origin/dev` except that now you have a new branch name and an attached `HEAD`.  **If you want to do any actual *work*, this is generally the way to go.**

---

<sup>5</sup>There is an exception when you tell your Git to clone by *tag* name.  In this case, your Git does a detached-HEAD checkout of the tag, and creates no branch name at all.

---

#### Finally, we get back to your question

> I want to update my local files so that I can work with the new files and updated ones.  Should I be using `git checkout remotes/origin/dev-1.2` to update my local directory?

I don't know what work, if any, you might have done so far in detached HEAD mode.  If you *have* made some new commits in this mode, you should start by creating a *branch name* to make your Git remember the hash ID of the *last* commit in your new chain.  For instance, let's say you started with:

```
          I   <-- origin/dev-1.1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          J--K   <-- origin/dev-1.2
```

You then ran `git checkout origin/dev-1.1`, which got you into detached-HEAD mode:

```
          I   <--  HEAD, origin/dev-1.1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          J--K   <-- origin/dev-1.2
```

Then you made a new commit or two:

```
            L   <-- HEAD
           /
          I   <--  origin/dev-1.1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          J--K   <-- origin/dev-1.2
```

Here, `L` stands in for some big ugly hash ID.  To avoid having to save this somewhere, we'd now like to have *Git* save it.  Pick a name—any name you like (within limits), but something that will *mean something to you*, such as `experiment-number-one` or whatever, and run `git checkout -b name` with that name.  Let's say you call it `exp-1` (for experiment number one).  Your `git checkout -b exp-1` gives you this as a drawing:

```
            L   <-- exp-1 (HEAD)
           /
          I   <--  origin/dev-1.1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          J--K   <-- origin/dev-1.2
```

which means you now have your own branch name by which you can easily find commit `L`.

Now, to work with/on the files that your colleague created, you can run:

```
git checkout dev-1.2
```

Since there isn't a `dev-1.2`, your own Git will look through your remote-tracking names and spot `origin/dev-1.2`.  This is the only match for `dev-1.2`, so your Git will *create* your own `dev-1.2` right now, and then check it out:

```
            L   <-- exp-1
           /
          I   <--  origin/dev-1.1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          J--K   <-- dev-1.2 (HEAD), origin/dev-1.2
```

Note how commit `L` remains easy to find via your branch name.

If you didn't create any commit `L`, you don't need to create a new name: the name `origin/dev-1.1` still suffices to find commit `I`.  But if that commit is *important* to you, you might still want to put a branch name on it, to make it quick to find.  Note that each time you have your Git connect to the Git over at `origin`, your Git can collect *new* commits from them, and will then update your own `origin/*` names to find the *new* commits you got from them.<sup>6</sup>

Once you have all this set up, [ekkom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65895164/1256452) about using `git cherry-pick` is a perfectly reasonable way to *copy* your hypothetical commit `L` to a new, slightly different commit—let's call it `L'` to remark on how it's similar to `L`—that would look like this:

```
            L   <-- exp-1
           /
          I   <--  origin/dev-1.1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          J--K   <-- origin/dev-1.2
              \
               L'  <-- dev-1.2 (HEAD)
```

Note how your `dev-1.2` will now be one commit "ahead of" their `dev-1.2` aka your `origin/dev-1.2`.

Experiment with `git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline`.  This has Git draw its version of the graphs I have been drawing here.  Git draws the commits vertically, with the newest ones at the top, instead of horizontally with the newest ones at the right.  Getting really nice drawings of the commits is sometimes vital, and `git log --graph` does not always cut it here.  For much more about this topic, see [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).

---

<sup>6</sup>If they've explicitly *removed* a commit from one of their branches, your Git will do a "forced update" of the corresponding remote-tracking name, backing it off that commit too.  If they completely deleted a branch name, your Git won't delete your own remote-tracking name unless you set `fetch.prune` to `true` or use `git fetch --prune` or `git remote update --prune`.  These are all decisions you must eventually make: I like to have `fetch.prune` set to true in my global Git config, so that my Git deletes remote-tracking names when they delete their branch names.

All of this is just a long-winded (though detailed with reasons *why*) way of saying that you should remember that *your* Git will take *their* name updates here, so if you value some particular commit for some particular reason, consider making up your own name to remember it, rather than relying on theirs.  But if you haven't looked at their commits, how much value do you think they have?  If you use `git checkout`'s name-creating trick to create your own local branch names, your Git *automatically* creates your own name.  Your branch names are *yours*, to deal with as you see fit.  This is mostly a non-problem.